# Callback from (List)Adapter to Activity

Tags: android

I have an Actvivity with a ListView, I set an adapter

```
MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

that adapter has a callback interface

```
OnPdfClickedListener callback; 

public interface OnPdfClickedListener {
    public void onPdfClicked();

}
```

and in the Activity

```
MyActvivity implements MyAdapter.OnPdfClickedListener
```

and

```
@Override
    public void onPdfClicked() {

    Log.d("TEST", "PDF CLICKED in ACTVIIVTY");

}
```

This is pretty much the same as described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), which works like charm for fragments. 
When trying the same from the adapter the callback object is null.

I also tried instantiating like

```
OnPdfClickedListener callback = new OnPdfClickedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPdfClicked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

I have no errors then but the respective method in the Activity is never called.

My question is 1. why isn't the callback object null when used in a fragment, it's never instantiated

and 2. how can I callback to an Activity from an adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. why isn't the callback object null when used in a fragment, it's never instantiated

Your `Activity` most likely isn't registered as a listener, with the `callback` variable you  created(which has nothing to do with the `Activity`) an instance of `OnPdfClickedListener` and (probably) used that when the event happened.

> how can I callback to an Activity from an adapter?

Pass a reference to the `Activity` to your `MyAdapter` class, cast it to `OnPdfClickedListener` and use that to call `onPdfClicked` instead of the current `callback` variable.

Comment: That works, thanks a bunch! I still don't really get why but I'll wrap my head around it :)

Comment: @Ascorbin To send the event(pdf clicked) you will call the `onPdfClicked()` method on an object of type `OnPdfClickedListener` which will be a listener/observer for the pdf clicked event(that object registered itself as an observer). In order to send the event to your `Activity` will need to call the `onPdfClicked` method on the `Activity` object(which is a `OnPdfClickedListener`) and that is why you need to pass the activity reference. In the fragment sample they use the callback variable to guard against a `NullPointerException` as the fragments have a more complicated life span.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

In your Activity which implements the interface:

```
new MyAdapter(this,....);
```

In your Adapter:

```
MyAdapter(Context context, ...){
  callback = (OnPdfClickedListener)context;
}
```

Comment: how did you solve??? i'm having the same problem! i've an adapter and i wish to send to its fragment that calls the adapter the position of the elements clicked! please help me thank you!